# Telethon → Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: telegram, message, telethon

I try to make a program to get the content of a Telegram Channel using Telethon (I'm begginer) :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = 12345678
api_hash = "zdzhdzud"
client = TelegramClient(None, api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='Channel_Test'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print("\n\n\n",event.raw_text,"\n\n\n")

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I get "RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback" 2 times.
Thank you

I expected to get a str for each message